# iOS: Best way to indicate popover?

Tags: ios, popover

I'm working on a simple music app for a client. There's a switch that triggers a backing track/beat that users can play sounds over that looks like this (the client insisted on the flower icon, don't judge):

[image]

Users are supposed to be able to choose between various beat patterns. I'm thinking about using a popover to allow users to change their beat pattern, but I'm not sure what the best way to indicate the popover is.

I've considered the detail disclosure button, but are there any ideas on better ways to either trigger a popover or allow a user to change the beat pattern?

[image]

Comment: Why do they need to be told a popover will appear?

Comment: @EvilClosetMonkey They don't really need to be told a popover will appear, but I don't want the feature to be completely hidden. I'm looking for a ways I may be able to make it clear that a user can choose from a selection of beats

Comment: does the flower icon have any other function than opening the popover?

Comment: It's all about informing user that "BEAT" element is interactive. To do so you can simply change font color of the "BEAT" button to blue one, which indicated interactivity on iOS devices.

Answer (score 1):

A gear icon would be more suitable than the *i* icon.

The latter tends to be used more for help, whereas the gear icon is used for preferences.

---

From a UX perspective, a button which tells the user the action it performs would be **less ambiguous**.

[image: Beat selection with button]

Applying a drop shadow can also be used to **indicate pliancy/pressability**.

---

However, as you're already using the flat flower icon as a button, I'm assuming you have a **flat interface**.

This isn't ideal from a UX perspective as **it's difficult to show pliancy in a flat interface**.

But using a similar style to an **iOS list item** might be an effective compromise. It's used commonly in iOS apps, so it should **meet the users expectations**.

[image: Select beat using an iOS list item style]

In your case, it might look like this:

[image: iOS Settings]